# Multiple apps from a developer account

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

We have a developer account and a published app on the ios app store. We are now launching another ios app.

Since both the apps are entirely different in functionalities, should we use the same developer account or is it beneficial to create another developer account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the accounts separate, it's easier to transfer control of the app to another developer in the future.

Comment: What makes transferring the app easier? You can transfer a single app just as easily from an account linked to multiple apps on the store by initiating a transfer request.

Comment: I think it's the record-keeping and intellectual property aspect. The developers who gave that feedback may have also had literally separate corporations set up for each, I don't recall.